# "Unwrapping" data retrieved from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, subscript

So I have managed to retrieve some `data` from `Firebase` and it looks like this when printed:

> [Resturant.CustomerList(key: "-LQQlhEmNZb8Kaha9uCk", customerLastName:
>   “Kendrick”, customerFirstName: “Anna”, customerSeat: "100",
>   customerOrder: “Noodle”, Timestamp: 1541290545703.0)]

Question: How do I unwrap them so I can put individual value into other String variables?
I tried many ways but I get errors such cannot subscript a value of type `[CustomerList]` with an index of type `String` if I do something like `let custName = self.list["Name"] as? String`

ps. `CustomerList` is a `struct`
pps. The print out of `list` is what is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a list of `CustomerList` objects i.e, `[CustomerList]` so you should first get a single object from this `list`. Lets say we want the very first object from this `list` to access its properties then we can do it as below,

```
if let firstCustomer = self.list.first {
    let firstName = firstCustomer.customerFirstName
    let lastName = firstCustomer.customerLastName
}
```

If you want to access an object at a specific `index` then you can do as below,

```
let index = 0
let customer = self.list[index]
let firstName = customer.customerFirstName
let lastName = customer.customerLastName
```

To find a particular `customer`, you can `filter` that as below,

```
let johny = self.list.filter{ $0.customerFirstName == "Jonhny"}.first {
    print(johny.customerLastName)
}
```

To get a custom list created from the customers list, you can use `map` as below,

```
let lastNamesArray = self.list.map({ $0.customerLastName })
```

Comment: Wow the first one solved the problem! Thank you so much! If you don't mind me asking, what does ".first" do in this context?

Comment: Actually its just a helper to get the element at `index` `0`(the first element's index) of the `array`.

Comment: Stupid question, how come I can't simply use list[0] to retrieve the data?

Comment: @Tomiris if you do not have any elements in your array and you try to access `list[0]`, it will throw an error - index out of range. But if you use `.first`, it will return `nil`. So if you safely unwrap `list.first`, it will never crash.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri that's exactly the error that I have got even when there are data in the array. Somehow .first works... Strange...

Comment: @Tomiris how is it strange? `.first` returns an optional, which means if an element exists, it returns that element, otherwise `nil`. Think of it like this. `if list[0] exists return list[0], else return nil`.

Comment: @Kamran A quick question: say I now have two sets of information returned from the query, how can I loop it through to grab a particular key pair value? For eg, how can I grab the individual Customers' last names from the following?


[Resturant.CustomerList(key: "-LQQlhEmNZb8Kaha9uCk", customerLastName: “Kendrick”, customerFirstName: “Anna”, customerSeat: "100", customerOrder: “Noodle”, Timestamp: 1541290545703.0), Resturant.CustomerList(key: "-LQQlhEmNZb8Kr32#Ck", customerLastName: “Depp”, customerFirstName: “Jonhny”, customerSeat: "99", customerOrder: “Rice”, Timestamp: 154134255703.0)

Comment: @Kamran thanks mate! I wonder if I can use a "for loop" to get put all the Last names in an array? Like this:


`let customersLastNameArray = [ ]  
customersNumber = list.count
var i = 0
for i <= customersNumber {
let index = i
let customer = self.list[index]
let lastName = customer.customerLastName
customersLastNameArray.append (lastName) 
   i++
}`

Comment: @Tomiris Added in the answer.